# Parametrize line given by intersection of sphere and plane

Tags: calculus, parametrization

Sphere of radius $1$ centred at $(x_0, y_0, z_0).$

The plane $z = cx$ where $c$ is a constant.

How do I find the parametrization of the intersection of the sphere and plane?

Answer (score 0):

Without caring too much about the range of the parameters in the various equations, we can write a parametric equation for the sphere
\begin{align}
x &= x_0+\sin\theta\cos\phi,\\
y &= y_0+\sin\theta\sin\phi,\\
z &= z_0+\cos\theta
\end{align}
and a parametric equation for the plane
\begin{align}
x &= s,\\
y &= t,\\
z &= cs.
\end{align}
Comparing we have
\begin{align}
&x_0+\sin\theta\cos\phi = s,\\
&y_0+\sin\theta\sin\phi = t,\\
&z_0+\cos\theta = cs
\end{align}
from which we can express $s,t,\phi$ in terms of, for example, $\theta$:
\begin{align}
s &= \frac{1}{c}(z_0+\cos\theta),\\
\phi &= \arccos\left(\frac{s-x_0}{\sin\theta}\right) = \arccos\left(\frac{z_0+\cos\theta-cx_0}{c\sin\theta}\right),\\
t &= y_0+\sin\theta\sin\phi=y_0\pm\sin\theta\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{z_0+\cos\theta-cx_0}{c\sin\theta}\right)^2}
\end{align}
Finally, the parametric equation of the curve could be written as
\begin{align}
x &= \frac{1}{c}(z_0+\cos\theta),\\
y &= y_0\pm\sin\theta\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{z_0+\cos\theta-cx_0}{c\sin\theta}\right)^2},\\
z &= z_0+\cos\theta.
\end{align}